# Change Directx Mesh Center

Tags: directx, rotation, scale, mesh, cube

I have created a mesh box in DirectX written in VB.NET. When I rotate and scale mesh, it is doing so from the center.

How do I change the mesh center similar to the following image:

[Mesh Center](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/806/18423269.png/)

Answer (score 1):

Translate the mesh matrix to the rotation/scaling center, apply rotation/scaling, then translate the matrix back. e.g.:

```
matWorld = Matrix.Identity

' Translate to rotation/scaling center
matWorld = matWorld * Matrix.Translate(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)

' Apply your rotation/scaling
matWorld = matWorld * Matrix.RotationZ(0.01)

' Translate from rotation/scaling center
matWorld = matWorld * Matrix.Translate(-0.1, -0.2, -0.3)

' Assign matWorld as world transformation matrix
device.Transform.World = matWorld
```

*Note: I didn't test the above, so there may be syntactical issues.*